# how to view default archetype in maven 3.0.4 in cmd prompt

Tags: maven, windows-xp, maven-3

I am newbie to maven and trying to learn maven using sonatype mavenbook. I am using windows XP command prompt to run the maven projets. Now I want to create new project but when I run

```
 mvn archetype:generate
```

it scrolls very fast and show only some last archetypes I want to see all the archetypes from first how can I stop the scrolling and view the available archetypes.

Please help

Comment: Just scroll up to the top in command prompt.

Comment: I tried but it does not show all. it start from archetype number 375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase Screen Buffer Size of your command prompt, right-click you command prompt blue title bar and open Properties:

[image]

Try increase the Screen Buffer Size Height, the default value set by windows is very small if I recall.